# Is it bad practice to have static functions with the same name in different C modules?

Tags: c

Bearing in mind this is C code, *not* C++...

...I have two modules that are doing the same thing, but on different interfaces on my micro. They need to run completely independently.

Is it bad practice to have the same named set of static functions in both files? In other words, almost all of the functions in the two modules are static functions and those that are static have exactly the same name.

I suppose I could even ask, is it *good* practice!

EDIT: In response to the debate below, here is some [partially pseudo] code:

```
static void DiscoverUnits(void)
{

   InitBus(); // Where this is one of two buses
   RandomiseAddresses(); // Again, one of two buses
   while (LongSeachAddress < MaximumLongAddress)
        {
        // Detect units, assign short addresses calling several functions
        // all of which are constantly accessing one of two buses
        // This could drag on for 20-30s! 
        }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The main issue arises from your statement:

> I have two modules that are doing the same thing, but on different interfaces on my micro. They need to run completely independently.

On the face of it, you need to create one lot of code which can be configured to work on either of the specific interfaces, so that you have two lots of the supporting data, but one copy of the code.

However, if there are insuperable reasons why that is not possible (I'd be curious to know what they are), then having the same function names as static functions in separate modules is permissible, and works fine.  It may make code search a little harder (you get two answers to every question about the repeated code), and you need to know how to work your debugger with such functions, but there's no reason why it should be regarded as all bad.

---

The question now has some sample code like this:

```
static void DiscoverUnits(void)
{
    InitBus(); // Where this is one of two buses
    RandomiseAddresses(); // Again, one of two buses
    while (LongSearchAddress < MaximumLongAddress)
    {
        // Detect units, assign short addresses calling several functions
        // all of which are constantly accessing one of two buses
        // This could drag on for 20-30s! 
    }
}
```

The example code might be revised to read more like this:

```
struct BusDescriptor
{
    const char *bus_name;
    uintptr_t   bus_lo_address;
    uintptr_t   bus_hi_address;
    uintptr_t   bus_search_address;
    int         num_units;
    …
};

static void DiscoverUnits(struct BusDescriptor *bdp)
{
    InitBus(bdp); // Where this is one of two buses
    RandomiseAddresses(bdp); // Again, one of two buses
    while (bdp->bus_search_address < bdp->bus_hi_address)
    {
        // Detect units, assign short addresses calling several functions
        // all of which are constantly accessing one of two buses
        // This could drag on for 20-30s! 
    }
}
```

There is absolutely no problem with the `DiscoverUnits()` function taking 30 seconds in one thread if it is reentrant and the other thread can also run the same function on the data for the other bus at the same time — which is the sort of concurrency that threads provide.

Note that I've assumed that `LongSearchAddress` and `MaximumLongAddress` are static variables in the two files containing substantially identical code.  I've translated them into references to the `struct BusDescriptor` type that I've created to capture all the state associated with one of the two buses.  I assume there'll be a non-static function, perhaps `int SetBusDescriptor(struct BusDescriptor *bdp, const char *name)` — or, more likely, a slightly more complex interface — that can be used to set the context for each bus.  When each 'bus master' thread is created, it will be given its own `struct BusDescriptor` pointing to the bus that it is to manage.  The two invocations will be given different buses to manage, of course.

Comment: It's because they are two entirely separate threads in FreeRTOS. I can't have two different threads accessing the functions at the same time and I don't want to have them locking each other out with a semaphore. A lot of the stuff is going on with [different] timer interrupts and pin interrupts, so [I think] it would a bad idea to share the functions between the two threads. I'm happy to be told my thinking is wrong though!

Comment: Waddya mean?  If the functions only access thread-local storage, or use mediated access to global storage, or are passed the data structure to use, then you can have two copies of the same function working on different data in different threads — unless FreeRTOS has completely redefined the rules of multi-threading code.  It might take time to work out what you've got to do, but you should be able to write the code so that all the variables used by each thread are separate from the variables used by the other thread.  Constants aren't a problem, of course.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ You might need to create a structure to hold the variables.  You should not have to worry about the timers interfering if the separate modules work correctly at the moment.  However, if you've not designed the code with this in mind, the short-term cost may be larger than the short-term benefit, but the double-maintenance problem you're setting yourself up with will almost certainly be a lot less effective and beneficial in the medium term, let alone the long run.

Comment: @DiBosco: You are confused!  There is no problem for different threads to share the same code and execute the same functions concurrently.  It is actually a good thing to have less code as it allows the CPU to use its cache more efficiently.  The problem is for data access.  As long as your functions do not access shared data such as global data or static local variables carelessly, they can be shared by different threads.

Comment: @DiBosco: You should post the code for these functions.  We can explain what is a problem and what is not.  I suspect your 'functions' access static data, and therefore would step on each others toes.  Passing the data specific to each thread by reference (passing a pointer to struct for example)  would allow you the share the code.

Comment: It's entirely possible that I am confused and just don't have a good enough understanding [yet]. There are obviously certain functions which absolutely have to be different, such as the timer interrupts and the pin interrupts. However, there is,  for example, one function that spends a long time sending out messages, getting responses, determining what's on the bus and assigning addresses once it gets a response back. I don't see how that thrashing away for tens of seconds on one interface, would not lock out the other thread that would want to access its bus concurrently.

Comment: Have added some code in an attempt to explain. Not sure I have done an even half decent job. It's complex and the end of a long day! Maybe I should go away, think about what you have said and work out a way to do this more in the way you are suggesting. We're kind of veering way off course of the original question! :D